# $\mathcal{L}$ has no negative eigenvalues. Provide conditions on $p, q, r$ such that that above result generalizes to this $\mathcal{L}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

(a) Consider the operator $\mathcal{L}=-d^2 / d x^2$ on $x \in[a, b]$. Prove that if we choose boundary conditions (BCs) such that
$$
\left.f(x) f^{\prime}(x)\right|_{x=a} ^{x=b} \leq 0
$$
for all (real-valued) $f(x) \in \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{L})$ that satisfy the BCs, then $\mathcal{L}$ has no negative eigenvalues.

(b) Suppose that $\mathcal{L}=p(x) d^2 / d x^2+q(x) d / d x+r(x)$ for continuous functions $p, q, r$ on $[a, b]$. Provide conditions on $p, q, r$ such that that above result generalizes to this $\mathcal{L}$.

I am reading Teschl and trying to solve some questions from arbitrary problems posted online and I am getting stuck almost everywhere. Teschl is so tough for me. I can hopefully get some understanding with your help. If you have some hint or way out from here. Please let me know. Also if you feel there is a lucid book where I get help of subject and problems. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for (b): Suppose $\mathcal Lf=\lambda f$, then (using integration by parts)
\begin{align}
\lambda\int^b_af^2dx&=\int^b_af\mathcal Lf\;dx=\int^b_a(pff''+qff'+rf^2)dx\\
&=[pff']^b_a+\int^b_a(-(pf)'f'+qff'+rf^2)dx\\
&=[pff']^b_a+\int^b_a(-p(f')^2+(q-p')ff'+rf^2)dx
\end{align}
If $p'=q$ and $p\leq 0$ and $r\geq 0$ and $p(a)=p(b)$, then we see that $\lambda\int^b_af^2dx\geq 0$, thus $\lambda\geq 0$. Hence $\mathcal L$ cannot have negative eigenvalues. Part (a) is just a special case of this.

Note that the condition $p'=q$ allows the operator to be written in divergence form
$$\mathcal Lg={d\over dx}\left(p(x){dg\over dx}\right)'+r(x)g$$
which is the form Sturm–Liouville operators are usually assumed to take. This condition makes sure the operator is symmetric (assuming the right boundary conditions holds) in the sense that $\int g_1\mathcal Lg_2dx=\int g_2\mathcal Lg_1dx$.

Comment: Why is it $qff"$ in the 2nd line?

Comment: Typo, should be $qff'$, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Part (a):
\begin{align}
        \int_a^b(\cal{L}f)fdx & =\int_a^b(-f'')fdx \\ &=\int_a^b(-f'f)'+f'f'dx \\ &=-f'f|_a^b+\int_a^b f'f'dx
\\ &\ge \int_a^b f'f'dx
\end{align}
If $\mathcal{L}f=\lambda f$, then applying the above results in $\lambda\int_a^b f^2 dx \ge \int_a^b (f')^2dx \ge 0$, which forces $\lambda \ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks for a), I upvoted. How about part b)?